# MSSQL conditional check inside of "INSTEAD OF UPDATE " trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, database-trigger

Working with MSSQL2008.

I have two tables.

```
TableResource
-------------
ID [bigint]
Attribute1 [int]
Attribute2 [int]
Attribute3 [int]
VersionId [uniqueidentifier]
```

and

```
TableResourceHistory
--------------------
ID [bigint]
Attribute3History [int]
HistoryDate [datetime]
VersionId [uniqueidentifier]
```

I have an `instead of update` trigger which needs to accomplish two things:

- IF the field "`TableReResource.Attribute3`" has changed, THEN write a history record to the history table with the "old" Attribute3 value AND ALSO modify the "`TableResource.VersionId`" field of the `TableResource` table.
- IF there is no change in "`TableReResource.Attribute3`", then just pass-through the UPDATE.

Here is what I have so far, but I'm having trouble coming up with the equality comparison to trigger the history log.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_UpdateResourceHistoryVersionId] ON [dbo].[TableResources]
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN                                           

-- ?? IF inserted.Attribute3 = deleted.Attribute3
-- ??  THEN we just pass the UPDATE through

UPDATE [TableResources]
SET 
    VersionId = inserted.VersionId,
    Attribute1 = inserted.Attribute1,
    Attribute2 = inserted.Attribute2        
FROM Inserted, TableResources
WHERE Inserted.ID = TableResources.ID

-- ??? ELSE, the Attribute3 field was updated, and we perform the history log
-- ??? and give it a new version number

-- History Log
INSERT TableResourceHistory (Attribute3History, HistoryDate, VersionId)
SELECT NEWID(), GETUTCDATE(), deleted.VersionId
FROM deleted    

-- pass through the update, but assign a new VersionId
UPDATE [TableResources]
  SET 
    VersionId = NEWID(),
    Attribute1 = inserted.Attribute1,
    Attribute2 = inserted.Attribute2        
FROM Inserted, TableResources
WHERE Inserted.ID = TableResources.ID   

END
```

Any ideas?  TIA!

Comment: Your comments inside the code is confusing. What do you mean by pass-through the UPDATE

Comment: @prd It was my understanding that with an 'Instead Of' trigger the original operation (the original Update which caused this trigger to fire) will not be executed.  Therefore, I want to  "pass through" or "re-submit" the update to make sure it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

History table insert will happen only when there is change in the `Attribute3`.

Try this

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_UpdateResourceHistoryVersionId]
ON [dbo].[TableResources]
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

  BEGIN

      IF EXISTS(SELECT 1
                FROM   inserted i
                       JOIN deleted d
                         ON i.ID = d.ID
                            AND i.Attribute3 = d.Attribute3)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE T
            SET    VersionId = inserted.VersionId,
                   Attribute1 = inserted.Attribute1,
                   Attribute2 = inserted.Attribute2
            FROM   Inserted I
                   JOIN [TableResources] T
                     ON I.ID = T.ID
                   JOIN deleted d
                     ON i.ID = d.ID
                        AND i.Attribute3 = d.Attribute3
        END

      IF EXISTS(SELECT 1
                FROM   inserted i
                       JOIN deleted d
                         ON i.ID = d.ID
                            AND i.Attribute3 <> d.Attribute3)
        BEGIN
            INSERT TableResourceHistory
                   (Attribute3History,HistoryDate,VersionId)
            SELECT Newid(),
                   Getutcdate(),
                   d.VersionId
            FROM   deleted d
                   JOIN Inserted i
                     ON i.ID = d.ID
                        AND i.Attribute3 <> d.Attribute3

            -- pass through the update, but assign a new VersionId
            UPDATE T
            SET    VersionId = Newid(),
                   Attribute1 = inserted.Attribute1,
                   Attribute2 = inserted.Attribute2
            FROM   Inserted I
                   JOIN [TableResources] T
                     ON I.ID = T.ID
                   JOIN deleted d
                     ON i.ID = d.ID
                        AND i.Attribute3 <> d.Attribute3
        END
  END
```

If something is wrong or not workking as expected then revert back in comment section below this answer

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it
Fist insert into the history and then update
I couldn't see any update of your Attribute 3 but i did put it in my trigger
Also The ID in the History log seemed to be the only link connecting the tables so i guess its not a primary key in the historytable

```
 CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_UpdateResourceHistoryVersionId] ON [dbo].[TableResources]
    INSTEAD OF UPDATE
    AS
       SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN    

    -- History Log, insert the old Attribute3 value (If in the Set values)
    IF UPDATE(Attribute3)
    BEGIN
       INSERT TableResourceHistory (ID, HistoryDate, Attribute3History, VersionId)
       Select i.ID, GETUTCDATE(), d.Attribute3, d.versionId
       FROM inserted i 
       INNER JOIN deleted d on i.ID = d.ID
       WHERE i.Attribute3 <> d.Attribute3
    END

    -- Update the table Use NewID() when Attribute3 differs
    UPDATE T         SET 
        VersionId = Case when UPPDATE(Attribute3) AND i.Attribute3 <> d.Attribute3 then NewID() ELSE i.VersionId END,
        Attribute1 = i.Attribute1,
        Attribute2 = i.Attribute2,
        Attribute3 = i.Attribute3
    FROM [TableResources] T 
    INNER JOIN inserted i on i.ID = T.ID
    INNER JOIN deleted d on d.ID = i.ID

END
```

EDIT:
Chris made me aware of the UPDATE(Field) function.

Best Regards Lars Skogshus
With complements to [Chris Chilvers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/35233/chris-chilvers)

Comment: You can also make use of `IF UPDATE(Attribute3)` to avoid the insert when the column was never updated https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx You still need the `i.Attribute3 <> d.Attribute3` check.

Comment: I don't see how my code could insert a row when an updated row hasn't changed the Attribute3

Comment: It won't, `IF UPDATE(Attribute3)` just avoids having to scan the updated/inserted tables when it's is known that the column was never updated (i.e. the column wasn't listed in the `SET ...` clause).